# A fast and optimize way to extract inner repeated identifiers using Scala parser

Tags: parsing, scala

I have defined these grammatic rules in Scala:

```
def root = rep(block)
def block = ("block" ~ blockName ~ "{" ~ definition ~ "}")
def blockName = ident
def definition = creation ~ destruction ~ upgrades
def creation = "creation" ~ "{" ~ duration ~ cost ~ "}"
def destruction = "destruction" ~ "{" ~ duration ~ "}"
def upgrades = "upgrades" ~ "{" ~ rep(ident ~ "{" ~ duration ~ cost ~ "}") ~ "}"
def duration = "duration" ~ "=" ~ wholeNumber
def cost = "cost" ~ "=" ~ repsep(resource, ",")
def resource = (resourceType ~ "*" ~ wholeNumber)  
def resourceType = "wood" | "metal" | "food"
```

and my input string is

```
"""
block citytown {
  creation {
    duration = 100
    cost = food * 10, wood * 10
  }
  destruction {
    duration = 100
  }

  upgrades {
    level1 {
      duration = 100
      cost = wood * 200  , food * 10
    }
    level2 {
      duration = 100
      cost = food * 30 , food * 10
    }
  }

}"""
```

I need a fast and optimize way to extract identifiers and values of the cost and duration in each block. I tried to use `^^` operator, but did not seem to useful for repeated inner values